# How do I delete ContentTypes in Bolt.cm?

Tags: bolt-cms, contenttypes

I've just installed [Bolt CMS](http://bolt.cm) and it offered to generate some sample content, which I did. So now there are 3 contenttypes: pages, entries, and showcases.

I want to keep the pages and entries but don't want the showcases. How do I remove them? I can remove the section from the `contenttypes.yml` file and they disappear from the front-end, but it still leaves the `bolt_showcases` table in the database, and also 'showcases' rows in other tables like `bolt_taxonomy`.

Do I need to delete all this manually? How do I make sure I've removed all traces of an old contenttype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contenttype records are limited to a single table. The only thing that escapes that boundary is taxonomy relationships.

To achieve what you want, delete the Showcase records in the UI, that will remove the relationships, if any, then you can safely drop the `bolt_showcases` table.